# Toggle disclosure triangle?

Tags: swift, nsbutton

I'm just trying to create a simple disclosure triangle to reveal some text when pressed.

But I can't figure out how to make the triangle to go from the up to down position.

Here's what I've got:

```
@IBOutlet weak var previewButtonOutlet: NSButton!

@IBAction func previewButonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    // If off turn On
    if previewButtonOutlet.state == 1 {
        previewButtonOutlet.state = 0
    } else {
        // If on turn off
        if previewButtonOutlet.state == 0 {
            previewButtonOutlet.state = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there is no need for code to make it rotate the triangle. That is automatic with the button press.